# Android XML design in 10.1 tab but do not support other screen resolution

Tags: android

I have used dp as my unit to scale the size of objects in the design. I designed the xml interface in 10.1 in WXGA and can run properly in this device. However, when I try to install in other screen size, for example, 4.7 in WVGA , the objects(including images, buttons, text) are extremely larger than normal. This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/loginback" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="550dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword" >

        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="600dp"
           android:text="Log Masuk" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="330dp"
            android:text="Pengguna Baru?Daftar di sini" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
           android:text="Nama Pengguna: "
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
           android:text="Kata Laluan: "
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="550dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do to enable my apps can be viewed on other smaller screen devices?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to make different layout and drawable folders and put your xmls and images according to your screen resolution:

For supporting multiple screen sizes check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

and for designing multiple screens check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Comment: Does it mean i need to create another xml design for small,medium,large,xlarge screen?And the images used should I resize?Do I need use smaller images for small xml design?

Comment: no you have to put your xml design into it .. and made changes according to resolution